# How the runtime traces assemblies

Tags: .net, frameworks, clr, .net-assembly, assemblies

Goodmorning everyone!

I was wondering if anyone helps me understand how the .Net runtime "traces / selects" the assembly to be executed.

I created a class library (Database) and defined it as version 1.0.0.0 I then created a second version of it with the signature change of some methods and defined it as version 2.0.0.0

Both were installed in the GAC with the same snk signature key.

At this point I create a class library (Test) that references the 1.0.0.0 version of Database from the GAC and then I create a console application that references the 2.0.0.0 version instead. Database and which also references the new Test class library. The console application also instantiates a Database class

I expected each assembly to use the version to which it refers, instead I realize that version 2.0.0.0 is always used also from the Test class library. Is this behavior normal? Am I wrong? Do I have a way to make each assembly use a specific version of an assembly in the GAC?

I hope I explained myself.

Thanks to those who will help me clarify.

Comment: It is not normal.  You must provide the trace you get from Fuslogvw.exe so we can see what is going on.

Comment: So should each assembly use the version in the GAC to which it is referenced? I try with Fuslogvw